# Can't resolve pylint invalid-name (C0103)

Tags: python, pylint

One of my methods has an attribute named `ai` (as in, artificial intelligence), which is tripping up `pylint`:

```
C0103: Attribute name "ai" doesn't conform to snake_case naming style (invalid-name)
```

I would like to avoid having to disable `pylint` if at all possible, but I'm not sure what the actual issue is here, though changing the name to `a_i` solves the issue, but I think that's just disgusting as a variable name.

Comment: You may also wish to change the regular expression `attr-rgx` in your `pylintrc` file so that `ai` is an accepted attribute name.  Alternatively you can call pylint with the `--attr-rgx` option.

Comment: @python_user I'm aware of the functionality of ignoring errors in specific blocks, but I would like to avoid disabling the linter if possible to not clutter the code with cruft.

Comment: @qouify That looks promising, I'd prefer to change settings of `pylint` itself, though the `--attr-rgx` option seems a bit daunting to use. I'll have a look at it though.

Comment: Your suggestion prompted me to dive into `pylint`s configurable properties, I've opted to set `good-names=ai` in a `.pylintrc` file in my project.

Comment: Sounds like a good choice, better than using modifying `attr-rgx` if you have very few such cases.

Answer (score 3):

Solved by adding a `.pylintrc` file in the root of my project, containing:

```
[HEADER]

good-names=ai
```